# Multiplying dataframe with series for rows with matching index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
data1 = {'value1': [100, 150, 200, 250, 300],
        'value2': [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, .9],
        'value3': [13, 16, 17, 23, 27]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1, index=['product_1','product_2','product_3','product_4','product_5'])
print(df)

           value1  value2  value3
product_1     100     0.2      13
product_2     150     0.4      16
product_3     200     0.6      17
product_4     250     0.8      23
product_5     300     0.9      27
```

I now want to multiply it with a series such that the entire row gets multiplied with the series value if the indices match. If not, nan should be included in the dataframe. The series looks like this:

```
data2 = {'product_1': 1, 'product_4': 2, 'product_5': 3}
ser = pd.Series(data2)
```

So output should look like this:

```
           value1  value2  value3
product_1     100     0.2      13
product_2     nan     nan     nan
product_3     nan     nan     nan
product_4     500     1.6      46
product_5     900     2.7      81
```

I tried it by combining .loc with .merge (e.g. `merge = df.loc[df.index==ser.index, :].mul(pd.Series(ser, index=df.index),axis='index')` ) but in that case, dataframe and series are required to have the same length. Any suggestions how to do this efficiently? My actual dataframe is a lot bigger than this example so ideally I don't have to call columns individually and I also would like to avoid to first have to fill up the series with nan for those indices that are not included compared with the dataframe. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You just need the specify the correct axis for alignment: `df.mul(ser, axis=0)`

Comment: It can be so simple sometimes! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments:

```
df.mul(ser, axis=0)
```